# graphQL on .net. Any thoughts?

Tags: .net, api, graphql

I need to test graphql on a .net environment. It should be on a .net environment.

Any hints where I can start? I already have the graphql official docs and I was already googled too. I need help "only" with the .net part of the problem.

Any docs, examples, libraries?

Comment: and what is the .net part of the problem?  what is not working for you?  please edit your post with an example - preferably with something that we can reproduce.  maybe even give this document a read:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just want help to start. I'm doing this wrong?

Comment: That link I provided about how to ask is very helpful when it comes to asking questions here that can be answered effectively.  Typically here on SO, we answer specific questions with specific answers - your question is broad, so therefore the answer is broad as well, which (from what I understand) is counter to what  SO intends to do.  That said, in my post below I have tried to answer the questions you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want help to start (as you said in the comments) I would suggest taking a look at this library: [graphql-dotnet on github](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet)

Without knowing what you have tried, this is about all I can offer.